# expand existing array output

Tags: php, arrays, append

I have this code, which is a custom slide script that I'm using for my wordpress theme:

```
$class = shortcode_atts( array('text_color' => '#ffffff', 'image' => '', 'video_vimeo' => '', 'video_youtube' => '', 'video_mp4' => '', 'video_ogg' => '', 'video_webm' => '', 'video_poster' => '', 'slide_desc' => '', 'slide_horizontal' => '', 'slide_fitscreen' => '', 'slide_noresize' => ''), $atts );

            if($class['slide_desc'] != ''){ $slide_desc = $class['slide_desc']; /* $slide_desc = htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace("*", '"', $slide_desc)); */ $slide_desc = "title=\"".$slide_desc."\""; }
            if($class['text_color'] == '#ffffff'){ $text_color = 'text_white'; }else{ $text_color = 'text_black'; }
            //if($class['slide_desc'] != ''){ $slide_desc = '<div style="opacity: 1; display: block;" id="content"><div class="container_12"><div class="grid_9"><h1 class="page-title" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">'.$class['slide_desc'].'</h1></div></div>'; }
            if($class['image'] != ''){
                $image = $class['image'];
                if($class['slide_horizontal'] == 'true'){ $horizontal = 'slide_horizontal '; }else{ $horizontal = ''; }
                if($class['slide_horizontal'] == 'true' || $class['slide_fitscreen'] == 'true'){ $slide_fitscreen = 'slide_fitscreen'; }else{ $slide_fitscreen = ''; }
                return '<img class="myimage '.$text_color.' '.$horizontal.$slide_fitscreen.'" src="'.$image.'" alt="" '.$slide_desc.' />';
```

So, in this sample code what I want to do is to output also this : `<?php echo do_shortcode('[daisy]'); ?>` on      every image, video.

I'm not so good at php and I think is something pretty simple but I don't know where and how exactly I need to append this code ( `<?php echo do_shortcode('[daisy]'); ?>` ) to be displayed on every slide. 
Any hints, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please give a clearer description of what you're trying, and how it's not working. This code sample is too epic to be helpful. Try to minimize the irrelevant code.

Comment: I think now it's clearer